# Исключить в foreach по id

Tags: php, foreach

Ребят подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли как-то исключить вывод определенных данных по ID используя foreach?

Вот код который выводит данные:

```
 <?php foreach($props_fieldsets as $fieldset){ ?>                                        
      <?php foreach($fieldset['fields'] as $prop){ ?>
           <?php if (isset($props_values[$prop['id']])) { ?>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                       <?php html($prop['title']); ?>                                       
                 </div>
           <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

Мне нужно показать все, кроме данных у которых ID - 124 и 125.
Если не затруднит, рабочий пример.
Спасибо.

Comment: думаю лучше сначала отфильтровать массив, а затем уже выводить данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach($props_fieldsets as $fieldset){ ?>                                        
      <?php foreach($fieldset['fields'] as $prop){ ?>
           <?php if (isset($props_values[$prop['id']])) { ?>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                       <?php html($prop['title']); ?>                                       
                 </div>
           <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
```

А ID, это, я так полагаю, $prop['id']?

Если да, то можете строку 
`if (isset($props_values[$prop['id']]))` 
заменить на `if (isset($props_values[$prop['id']]) && ($prop['id'] != '124' && $prop['id'] != '125'))`

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы не хардкодить айдишнки можно создать массив с исключениями

```
$id_to_remove = array (124,125);
```

Далее

```
if (isset($props_values[$prop['id']]))
```

Заменить

```
if (isset($props_values[$prop['id']]) AND !in_array($prop['id'],$id_to_remove))
```

В итоге, если потребуется убрать еще какие-то id не нужно будет менять код, достаточно добавить новые id в массив $id_to_remove

Comment: Попробовал ваш вариант. Работает, но исключает только последний ID, т.е. 125, а 124 остается.

Comment: Да, действительно была ошибка, изменил array_search на in_array теперь должно работать правильно

Comment: Спасибо. Работает:-)

Answer (score -2):

Поставить проверку

```
if id=!124 || id=!125
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, куда вставить данный код. в php не понимаю.

Comment: Я тоже в самом php не силен :) Ниже подсказали как и куда ее вписать.

Comment: Ну вообще здесь не || надо, а &&, потому что оба условия не должны выполняться, а не только одно.

Comment: Всем спасибо за отклик. Вопрос решен:-)